# Select rows and group by id and sort for n latest rows (by date)

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, aggregation, top-n

I have the following set of data returned by a select:

```
date          code     
23/01/2012    AA123
24/01/2012    AA123
29/01/2012    AA123
06/07/2012    AA123
17/02/2012    BB123
20/02/2012    BB123
04/06/2012    BB123
```

The select gives all the data for each code (ordered by code). I only want to return the rows for the latest 2 dates for each code. The data to be returned would be as follows:

```
date          code     
23/01/2012    AA123
24/01/2012    AA123
17/02/2012    BB123
20/02/2012    BB123
```

How do i achieve the desired results? I have tried to use

```
select date, code
from table
where x,y,z
and rownum < 2 
order by code desc;
```

but it only returns the top 2 rows -

Comment: *Latest* or *oldest*? Your result includes the *oldest two*.

Answer (score 6):

```
select
  date,
  code
from
    (select 
      date, 
      code,
      dense_rank() over (partition by code order by date) as rank
    from 
      table
    where 
      x,y,z)
where
  rank <= 2
order by 
  code desc;
```

Instead of `dense_rank`, you can also use `rank` or `row_number`. There's a slight difference between them, so one might fit your needs better than the other.

Comment: partition by / dense_rank() --> which db?

Comment: Oracle, as this question is tagged.

Comment: @TJ-: nearly all modern DBMS nowadays.

Comment: many thanks - i used rank() as i wanted to assign a sequential order.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this maybe. i didn't test.

```
select date,code from table A where (select Count(*) from table B where A.code=B.code AND A.date > B.date ) < 2
```

Comment: i test it now. it works. [link]http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6b144/4. i misunderstood the question.i noticed that latest dates have been requested. but example shows oldest dates. i wrote the query about the example. so @user1726582 must only change A.date > B.date to A.date < B.date in the query.